# Infinite loop and crash when trying to execute this code in Worksheet_Change method

Tags: vba, excel

So I have developed an algorithm that breaks down a word into multiple parts based on certain rules about letter occurrences within the word. I have managed to debug the entire algorithm and now for the sake of convenience for the user, I am trying to put it into a Worksheet_Change method like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim arr() As String
    Dim i As Byte
    Dim j As Byte

    If (Target.Column = 1) Then
        If (Target.Value <> "") Then
            arr() = BreakupWord("perform")
            For i = 1 To 10
                Cells(Target.Row, i + 1) = arr(i)
            Next i
        ElseIf (Target.Value = "") Then
            For j = 1 To 10
                Cells(Target.Row, i + 1) = ""
            Next j
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Basically, the variable arr() stores the broken down components of the word "Target" in its array and via a For loop I try to print out the contents into cells on the worksheet ***considering the user has made a change only in column A of the worksheet as given by the conditions***

Now, the problem is such: I tested multiple words one line after the other and the code runs smoothly. However, if I go to an already entered word in ***column A*** and delete it via **Backspace** or **Delete**, my code seems to enter an infinite loop and Excel crashes. What is possibly the problem and how can I avoid it?

Comment: Here's a good reference for [Worksheet_Change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860894/ms-excel-crashes-when-vba-code-runs)

Answer (score 2):

You need to turn off events before changing values on the same worksheet or you trigger another event.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim arr() As String
    Dim i As Byte
    Dim j As Byte

    If (Target.Column = 1) Then
        APPLICATION.ENABLEEVENTS = FALSE
        If (Target.Value <> "") Then
            arr() = BreakupWord("perform")
            For i = 1 To 10
                Cells(Target.Row, i + 1) = arr(i)
            Next i
        ElseIf (Target.Value = "") Then
            For j = 1 To 10
                Cells(Target.Row, i + 1) = ""    'should i be j?
            Next j
        End If
    End If
    APPLICATION.ENABLEEVENTS = TRUE
End Sub
```

You are not covering a situation where Target could be more than a single cell.

I do not understand the nested If ... ElseIf ... End If. It reads If not blank ElseIf blank.

Does BreakupWord return a 1-based array? By default a 1-D array is zero-based.

Comment: Oh Thanks!! I'm relatively new to VBA so I had no idea you could even turn off events. I dabbled with the If Else construct to make it a nested if without else to see if that made a difference but it didn't. Also, my 1-D arrays are always with Base 1. I use Excel 2010. Does that make a difference? I believe to make it 0-based you need an OPTION BASE 0 command at the start of the module.

Comment: Well, if something is not blank then by strict definition is that the else is blank. `ElseIf (Target.Value = "") Then` could be just `Else`. You haven't provided enough detail on purpose and sample data to suggest anything else.

Answer (score 0):

you've already been told about the relevant issue of avoiding recursive call of the same event handler

here's another code that:

- manages that issue
- adds an error trapping to prevent any error leave you with disabled event handling
- check for proper changed range to act on (one-cell range in column A)
- simplifies the cell writing

  ```
  Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
      Dim arr As Variant ' a Variant can handle arrays too

      With Target 'reference changed range
          If .Count = 1 Then ' if only one cell changed
              If .Column = 1 Then ' if changed cell in column "A"
                  On Error GoTo ExitSafely 'handle possible errors
                  Application.EnableEvents = False 'prevent subsequent sheet changing rise and infinite loop by calling recursively thsi very same sub
                  If .value <> "" Then
                      arr = BreakupWord("perform")
                      .Offset(, 1).Resize(, UBound(arr) - LBound(arr) + 1) = arr 'write next to changed cell into as many cells as array elements
                  Else
                      .Parent.Range(.Parent.Cells(.Row, .Parent.Cells.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft), .Offset(, 1)).ClearContents 'clear the content of any cell right of changed one
  '                    .Offset(, 1).Resize(, 10).ClearContents ' clear 10 cells right of changed one
                  End If
              End If
          End If
      End With

  ExitSafely:
      Application.EnableEvents = True
  End Sub
  ```

just be sure that your `BreakupWord()` function returns a `Variant` array, like for instance

```
Function BreakupWord(strng As String) As Variant
    '....
    BreakupWord = Array("1", "2", "3", "4")

    'in the end
    BreakupWord = Array("1", "2", "3", "4") ' or any other way to assign an array to BreakupWord 
End Function
```